# Generating a subset uniformly at random?

Tags: random, probability, subset

Here is an [implementation](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/c5ad394d0058d6965f6e) of a combinatorial algorithm to choose a subset of an n-set, uniformly at random. Since there are 2<sup>n</sup> subsets of an n-set, each subset should have a probability: 2<sup>-n</sup> of getting selected.

I believe I have implemented the algorithm correctly (please let me know if there is a bug somewhere). When I run the program with Java 7 on my Linux box however, I get results that I am not able to reason quite well. The mystery seems to be around the Random Number Generator. I understand that one needs to run the program a 'large number' of times to 'see that the distribution reaches uniformity'. The question however is **how large is large**. A few runs I did suggest that unless the number of times the experiment is done is >= 1 billion, the distribution of chosen subsets is quite nonuniform.

The algorithm is based on Prof. Herbert Wilf's combinatorial algorithms book where the implementation (slightly different) is done in Fortran and the distribution is more-or-less uniform even when the program is run only 1280 times.

Here are a few sample runs (there's some variation among the run when n is constant) to get a random subset of a 4-set:

1. Number of times experiment is done n = [1280](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/0a32b86e234e663a7b5e)
2. Number of times experiment is done n = [12,800](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/b9dbb2c3495bf22b3c41)
3. Number of times experiment is done n = [128,000](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/fc438c0f66a3e771ff09) (still 8 subsets only!)
4. Number of times experiment is done n = [1,280,000](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/af969aae8d5b34f8e021)
5. Number of times experiment is done n = [12,800,000](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/fd16c73894f40bd1361e) (now it starts making sense)
6. Number of times experiment is done n = [1,280,000,000](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/68e142da11e1b4092907) (this is okay!)

Would you expect such performance? How could Prof. Wilf achieve similar results with only **1280** iterations of an equivalent program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `ranInt()`, you reset the RNG. Therefore in the long run, these numbers are no longer random. 
Moved `Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());` to the top and add `static` to it

```
class RandomSubsetSimulation {
  static Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
  public static void main(String[] args) { ...
```

I am able to get the following results with 8-set

```
Total: 1000, number of subsets with a frequency > 0: 256
Total # of subsets possible: 256
```

Full results with 4-set

```
Frequencies of chosen subsets ....
                 [3] :         76,          4, 5.94
                 [4] :         72,          8, 5.63
                  [] :         83,         -3, 6.48
                 [1] :         90,        -10, 7.03
                 [2] :         80,          0, 6.25
              [3, 4] :         86,         -6, 6.72
              [2, 3] :         88,         -8, 6.88
              [2, 4] :         55,         25, 4.30
           [1, 2, 3] :         99,        -19, 7.73
           [1, 2, 4] :         75,          5, 5.86
           [2, 3, 4] :         76,          4, 5.94
              [1, 3] :         85,         -5, 6.64
              [1, 2] :         94,        -14, 7.34
              [1, 4] :         72,          8, 5.63
        [1, 2, 3, 4] :         71,          9, 5.55
           [1, 3, 4] :         78,          2, 6.09
Total: 1280, number of subsets with a frequency > 0: 16
Total # of subsets possible: 16
```

Comment: Fixed the original code [here](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/c5ad394d0058d6965f6e#file-randomsubsetsimulation-java-L52)